# Simple download/install script (OS X) that could be better

Tags: shell-script, osx

I'm new to shell scripting (OS X) and decided to try my hand at a basic script that downloads and installs Chrome.

```
#!/bin/bash -x

cd ~/Downloads
curl -O https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/CHFA/googlechrome.dmg
open ~/Downloads/googlechrome.dmg && sleep 10
cp -R /Volumes/Google\ Chrome/Google\ Chrome.app /Applications && open 
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
diskutil eject Google\ Chrome
```

The script *technically* works but only because of the `sleep 10` I put in there, and only because the dmg happens to launch within 10 seconds (which won't always be the case in the real world).

I've tried to link `open` and `cp` together with `&&`, but that doesn't work, and I get the error that /Volumes/Google\ Chrome/Google\ Chrome.app doesn't exist (because the previous command hasn't completed fully yet).

I don't think this script will have a lot of useful applications; again, I'm just trying to learn, but I'm just wondering if there is a better way to go about this.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be revised to use an "are we there yet?" sanity check rather than sleeping for a sixth of a minute:

```
#!/bin/bash -x

cd ~/Downloads
curl -O https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/CHFA/googlechrome.dmg
open ~/Downloads/googlechrome.dmg
while ! [[ -d /Volumes/Google\ Chrome/ ]]; do
   sleep 1
done
cp -R /Volumes/Google\ Chrome/Google\ Chrome.app /Applications && open 
/Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
diskutil eject Google\ Chrome
```

However, in the event that the `.dmg` fails to mount or for some reason mounts into another location, this will spin its wheels until the end of time.

Slightly better than handing this off to `open` though (which just asks Finder to pretend we double-clicked on the file), let's mount it ourselves:

```
#!/bin/bash -x
cd ~/Downloads
curl -O https://dl.google.com/chrome/mac/stable/CHFA/googlechrome.dmg
set -o pipefail
if mountpoint=$(hdiutil attach googlechrome.dmg | awk 'END { print $1 }'; then
   cp -R /Volumes/Google\ Chrome/Google\ Chrome.app /Applications && open 
   /Applications/Google\ Chrome.app
   hdiutil detach "$mountpoint"
fi
```

Comment: Genius! Totally worked, and since I passed the -x after the hashbang, I could see it working in real time! Thanks!

Comment: Does the "open" command return immediately or does it wait until the image is opened?

Comment: `open` returns immediately as soon as it finished telling MacOS to _start_ mounting the disk image, rather than when it's done being mounted, hence the need to wait until the directory is present.  Many `.dmg`s will take a few seconds to self-check before the mount point is brought online.  If it waited, there'd be no need to `sleep` at all.  The better answer is probably to mount the image directly rather than to hand it off to `open`.